# Like total suddenly missing from /posts/ graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I only just noticed that an application I worked on a few months ago is no longer pulling like counts from the Graph API using /PAGE_NAME/posts. I noticed that there was an October 2013 breaking change to the /POST_ID/likes/ which could affect what I'm doing. It says:

> Apps will be able to retrieve all likes on a post (rather than the first 4 as it is today) through paging. As a result of the functionality update, the like count will be moved to the summary field.

However it's not clear how to access this 'summary' field. On the /post/ API documentation it mentions the following fix.

> Requesting with summary=1 will also return a summary object containing the total_count of likes.

However adding summary=1 to a /posts/ query does not appear to do anything. Here is my query.

```
http://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_NAME/posts/?limit=24&fields=message,from,id,likes,actions,shares&summary=1&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Still no luck. Any ideas? This is super aggravating.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this parameter like this:

```
/posts?fields=likes.summary(1).limit(1)
```